# Redux: Actions and reducers for every resource?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm currently building an application that uses a lot of 'resources' and performs the same operations on them. Every resource (customers, projects, products, invoices) has a list, edit-form, CRUD operations and more.

You can imagine a lot of code repetition. I'm thinking of generalizing into a single 'Resource' with actions like FETCH_RESOURCE, RECEIVE_RESOURCES, etc. where the resource type is a parameter. The same can be done for components.

As I am new to Redux, I'm trying to find out if this is a good or a bad idea, and if it fits with the Redux philosophy. I've looked at Redux-CRUD, but it is still generating actions and reducers for every resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's *very* common to generalize repetitive/reusable CRUD logic like that.  However, the "copies" of the logic do need some way to distinguish between dispatched actions to know which "copy" is supposed to respond.

There's examples of this kind of pattern in the [Structuring Reducers - Reusing Reducer Logic](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ReusingReducerLogic.html) section of the Redux docs, and my [Redux addons catalog](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links) has large sections for existing libraries covering [entity management](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/entity-collection-management.md) and [action/reducer generation](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/action-reducer-generators.md).